# Can't bind to Angular 9 custom directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I wanted to create my own authentication directive, that hides content when user doesn't have the desired role.

Unfortunatelly, I get

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'appHasRole' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I followed every tutorial, every stack overflow question, nothing seem to help.

I have created the directive:

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../../security/auth.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasRole]'
})
export class HasRoleDirective {

  role: string;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
              private authService: AuthService) { }

  private updateView() {
    if (this.checkPermission()) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

  private checkPermission() {
    // logic for determining role
  }

  @Input()
  set hasRole(val) {
    this.role = val;
    this.updateView();
  }
}
```

Since I have multiple modules, I created SharedModule

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HasRoleDirective} from './directives/has-role.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HasRoleDirective],
  exports: [HasRoleDirective]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

Then importing the directive in my home page module (also tried it in the app.module)

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

And finally, using the directive in home.component.html

```js
<div class="button-group" *appHasRole="['admin']">
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add appHasRole in `@Input`, because it was looking for `hasRole` attribute.

If `@Input` doesn't have parameter Angular looks for an attribute with propertyName. If you pass parameter to the `@Input`, Angular looks for an attribute with the value of parameter passed.

```
@Input('appHasRole') 
   set hasRole(val) {
       this.role = val;
       this.updateView();
    }
```

Comment: I would not think of that! Works great. Sending a virtual beer 